# Bootstrap carousal with the last version of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

This demo using carousel works fine.. I mean clicking on next/previous button the images change.

Here is the code:

```
$('[id^="myCarousel"]').carousel();
```

Here is the demo using jquery 1.7.1: http://jsfiddle.net/S2rnm/300/
Here is the demo using jquery 1.8.2: http://jsfiddle.net/S2rnm/303/

If I try to upload the version of jQuery to 1.8.2, when I click on next/previous button the images do not change.
Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are the next/prev buttons?

Comment: @David, click on run. Then for next/prev button I mean the arrow right/left

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

changing the container div to this `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">` and changing the jquery selector to this `$('.carousel').carousel();` seems to work for me using 1.8.2 when changing your example in the fiddle 303 http://jsfiddle.net/c5GB3/

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer, actually I added the resource but as I said it does not slide the images when clicking on next/prev button. http://jsfiddle.net/S2rnm/303/

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't realise you could add resources like that in jsfiddle. I've updated my answer which seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong : `$('.carousel.slide').carousel();` but your carousel is just `<div id="myCarousel">`.

Furthermore, you need the classes for it to work properly, like that : `<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">`. Only the ID is optional.